# Getting the most out of Community-Wiki Answers

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

So, a couple of times I have used Community Wikis for answers that didn't directly answer the question, but provided a good starting point for making a good answer. But it seems that no one actually contributes to them. If they do expand on the Community Wiki, its only as their own post.

So the question is, is there an effective way to use community wikis to make better answers? Or does the reputation point system kill all usefulness of the community wiki answers?